# Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`).when trying to update state with value which comes from context.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-context, react-class-based-component

I am getting getSingleProduct function from context . and passing items id . This returns array of 1 object. Now I want to pass this item into this.state.singleItem above but I get this error.. I have also tried to store this data into context.js 's this.state but same error. If I create function above and execute this code. it says that contex is not defined .

```js
export default withRouter(
  class Details extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        id: this.props.router.params.id,
        singleItem: [], // I want to store item here
      };
      //this.getItem();
    }

    static contextType = ProductContext;

    getItem = (item) => {
      if (this.state.singleItem.length === 0 && this.context) {
        this.setState(() => {
          return {
            singleItem: item,
          };
        });
        console.log("executed?");
      }
    };
    render() {
      const { getSingleProduct } = this.context;
      const item = getSingleProduct(this.state.id);
      if (this.state.singleItem.length === 0) {
        this.getItem(item);
      }
      console.log(this.state.singleItem);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't seem correct to me to use this methods directly in the `render` method as you are invoking a `this.setState`. So probably that is your issue (hard to tell without a codesandbox).

So what you could try, is to wrap all of that state-handling-code and put it inside a `componentDidMount` or `componentDidUpdate` call as it corresponds with the react lifecycle for class components.

So it would end being something like this:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    id: this.props.router.params.id,
    singleItem: [], // I want to store item here
  };

  /* Binding function to be able to handle state modifications from there */
  this.getItem = this.getItem.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
  const { getSingleProduct } = this.context;
  const item = getSingleProduct(this.state.id);
  /* No need to validate this.state length because this method is called only before the first render */
  this.getItem(item);
}
```

For more info about class components lifecycle you can check [this link](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html).